# Can my boss force me to work because I'm not going to the companies Christmas lunch?

Tags: work-environment

I opted out of the works Christmas pub lunch because I couldn't commit to the day it is on. Originally my boss said' Oh well are you sure because we are shutting up shop for the afternoon..he then said if your'e not coming you can have the afternoon off then. 2 days later he says he now wants me to come in and work, and man the phones etc.. (denying/withdrawing his previous statement) and if I don't come in I won't get paid for the afternoon. Feel like I'm being punished.:(

**Can my boss force me to work because I'm not going to the companies Christmas lunch?**

Comment: Your paragraph is unclear, and I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: There's no question nor can I see one hidden anywhere in that paragraph. This is just a rant, voting to close.

Comment: @ChristopherEstep this is exactly what I am talking about in META where people selfishly vote to close. It takes 5 seconds to add a question. It is very obvious that the OP is wanting to know something along the line sof "Can my boss force me to work if I am not going to the companies lunch"

Comment: I thought I was getting a free day off,  I'm not getting a free day off.   I'm going to vent to random strangers on the Internet so they know I'm not getting a free day off.    This is just a rant so off topic.   Can your boss expect you to work on a paid day when you don't want to go to the planned social?  YES.

Comment: @Prodnegal -  but it's still a bad question,  the answer is simply Yes they can,  no discussion needed.

Comment: Your boss likely got told he had to have you work and that he was mistaken when he told you that you could have the afternoon off.  Or coworkers decided they didn't want to go either if they coudl have a free day off instead. MIstakes happen, circumstances change. You have to learn to accept these bumps in the road not get pissed off and upset. That does no one, including yourself, any good.  Things change and you will often be tasked to do things that you are not personally excited about. Tough luck. No sympathy.

Comment: Why couldn't you "commit to the day"? What would you have been doing if you weren't going to be at the party?

Comment: Once again:  Treat every **optional** workplace function as **MANDATORY**

Comment: @RichardU I have to partially disagree. If the function is held during working hours, it's mandatory in almost all cases. If it's during working hours BUT you had previously requested and been approved for time off before the function was announced, failure to attend shouldn't be a negative mark. If it's outside working hours, it should still be considered optional and employers should respect that employees may have previously-arranged commitments or other obligations which may prevent them from attending.

Comment: And if its mandatory during work hours, chances are the other option is work.  Not paid time off.

Comment: @Prodnegel Selfish? Do you think I get something out of closing questions?  There was no question and it's not the community's job to make up questions for the questioners. And as you've shown, editing into what was possibly an obvious question just changed the close reason.

Comment: @ChristopherEstep You are missing the point. An answer with 20 up-votes was also provided due to my edit. You focus on making sure questions are 100% on topic while I just want to help some people get an answer. If 20 people think it was a good one, I think that makes the question good enough as well.

Answer (score 22):

If you are being paid to work a day,  but are being offered a social event instead which you do no want to attend,  it is entirely reasonable for your boss to expect you to work instead.

If the event is unpaid,  it's reasonable for you to either have the day off,  or be paid to work.

Comment: Yes, that is very common. You can consider the paid work leave as an incentive to make people attend the company event. You cannot claim the incentive if you are not going to attend.